# как с помощью цикла в python добавить в массив обьекты с разным именем?

Tags: python, массивы, ооп

есть некий класс и экземпляр этого класса a. Как с помощью цикла for добавить в массив экземпляры этого класса чтобы их имена различались? пример: [a1, a2, a3, a4, a5]

Comment: Зачем? Какой в этом смысл?

Comment: для симуляции нужно чтобы на сцене было несколько обьектов

Comment: Ну так и положите экзепляры в массив. Все а млм а1 - это всего лишь именной контейнер для хранения инфы. Элемент массива(списка) это такой же контейнер

Comment: в процессе атрибуты обьектов будут изменятся, хотя наверное менять имена обьектов для этого не обязательно

Comment: Имя - это просто ярлычок на объект, чтобы ссылаться на этот объект из текста программы. В списке объекты лежат уже без всяких ярлычков. Т.е. даже если вы сделаете несколько имён для одного объекта через конструкцию вида `a1 = a`, и положите их в список, то там у них всё равно никаких имён не будет, это будет просто несколько раз тот же самый объект. Возможно, что вам нужно сделать несколько разных экземпляров класса, и складывать в список их?